# Kendo UI combobox freezes when doing server filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am getting around 6000 records that I need to bind to combobox. I am doing server filtering on it when user types at least 2 characters. It works fine for the first time but when I clear the combobox my page freezes.

Below is how I initiated my combobox.

```
$("#myList").kendoComboBox({
        filter: "startswith",
        dataTextField: "xName",
        dataValueField: "xId",
        template: '<span>#:xName# (#:gName#-#:gmName#)</span>',
        dataSource: viewModel.get("mydataList"),
        height: 400,
        autoBind: false,
        minLength: 2,
    }).data("kendoComboBox");
```

Below is how I have specified the datasource:

```
mydataList= new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                dataType: "json",
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return {
                        models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                    };
                }
            }
        },
        serverFiltering: true
    }
    );
```

Also please suggest if I can hide the dropdown arrow.

Comment: Why did you define your data source like that? Just use razor syntax. Also, post the controller action in which you do the filtering.

Comment: I have no other specific code to do filtering. this code itself do that . So if I type "AS" it pulls all the data stating with "AS" but if is delete "AS" the it freezes. It seems then the control tries to bind with all records.

Comment: Where in this code the filtering is done? Also, how can it be a server filtering without any server code (controller action) to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not server filtering. Just because you have set `serverFiltering: true` doesn't mean you're doing server filtering. That setting is only to tell the data source that you are using server filtering, but you need to actually implement it. You have 6000 records, which is a lot, and that's why your combo-box freezes. Also, you're using asp.net MVC, and the question is tagged with Kendo asp.net MVC, so you should use the Razor syntax. Here's how to do it.

**Your ComboBox:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
      .Name("myList")
      .DataTextField("xName")
      .DataValueField("xId")
      .Template("<span>#:xName# (#:gName#-#:gmName#)</span>")
      .Filter("startswith")
      .AutoBind(false)
      .Height(400)
      .MinLength(2)
      .DataSource(source => {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetMyList", "MyController");
          })
          .ServerFiltering(true);
      })
)
```

Then in your controller (MyConteroller in my example), you'll have an action that returns the filtered list:

```
public JsonResult GetMyList(string text) {
    // Here you put the logic to filter the data you had in myDataList in your question
}
```